# C++ DirectX Draw a .PNG sprite as window background

Tags: c++, directx

I was wondering if I can draw a .PNG sprite as background in my DirectX window I currently have it setup like this:

```
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);
```

It makes the background to a bluish color, but is it possible replace that line so it draws a sprite there instead?

Or should I just draw the sprite ontop of the background instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cover the background, just render a full-screen sprite. You don't need to `Clear` the color portion of the render target in this case since you'll be drawing every pixel. You'd still use `Clear` with `D3DCLEAR_STENCIL` and/or `D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER`, and you should draw the sprite without writing or reading the z-buffer (if any).

Of course, ideally you'd be using Direct3D 11 instead of the legacy Direct3D 9 API or any version of D3DX.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). `SpriteBatch` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) can easily draw a full-screen image in the background for Direct3D 11 as per [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Writing-custom-shaders).